GAM - blanquear RecPwdKeyDailyNumber y RecPwdKeyMonthNumber
En una KB integrada con GAM en Genexus17 U9, si un usuario intentó recuperar la contraseña 4 veces e intenta hacerlo una quinta, aparece el mensaje:
26 - No se permite cambiar la contraseña.

Para hacer esta validación, en la tabla de Usuarios de GAM existen dos atributos, los cuales se van incrementando cada vez que el usuario intenta recuperar la contraseña:

RecPwdKeyDailyNumber
RecPwdKeyMonthNumber

Para que el administrador de la seguridad pueda "desbloquear" desde el sistema el cambio de contraseña de un usuario que hizo 4 intentos o más, se realizó una acción para poner en 0 estos dos atributos con el siguiente código:
    &User.Load(&GUID)
    &User.RecPwdKeyDailyNumber = 0
    &User.RecPwdKeyMonthNumber = 0
    &User.Save()
    If &User.Success()
        commit
    Else
        &Errors = &User.GetErrors()
        For &Error in &Errors
            Msg(Format(!"%1 (GAM%2)", &Error.Message, &Error.Code))
        EndFor
    EndIf

Pero aunque siempre entra por el success, estos dos atributos no se actualizan y siguen siempre en 4.
¿Existe alguna restricción de parte de GAM para actualizar estos atributos? ¿Por qué es que con este código no se pueden poner en 0?

Los campos RecPwdKeyDailyNumber y RecPwdKeyMonthNumber para la API GAMUser son de solo lectura.
Para poder actualizarlos deberías hacerlo mediante Data View a la tabla User de GAM.
